# Find all differentiable function for which $f'(x)=177f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

**My try:**

 I think functions that meet the requirements of the task are: $$f(x)=c\cdot e^{177x}$$
Then I have:
$$f'(x)=c\cdot (\ln e) \cdot e^{177}\cdot 177=177c\cdot e^{177}=177f(x)$$
However I don't know how to prove that these are the only functions that I am looking for.

Have you some hints for me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation of proof nedeed: Why is $y'=c \cdot y$ always a exponential growth/decay function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132736/explanation-of-proof-nedeed-why-is-y-c-cdot-y-always-a-exponential-growth-d)

Comment: Starting with only the original differential equation, separation gives only this. There may be other ways of rewriting this but they should all be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=177$$
Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ gives
$$\ln{(f(x))}=177x+C_1$$
$$f(x)=e^{177x+C_1}=C_2e^{177x}$$
Where $C_2=e^{C_1}$

Comment: I think this won't explain why can't we have a different solution.

Comment: @Botond The only function of $x$ whose derivative is $y'/y$ is $\log y,$ where $y=f(x).$ Know any other ones?

Comment: @Allawonder The task is to prove that there isn't any other solution. And I don't see why would any of the answers here prove that if the functions $\eta$ and $\zeta$ both satisfies the differential equation then $\exists c \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $\eta = c \zeta$.

Comment: This does not find the negative $c$, or $c=0$, of the OP, because you're tacitly assuming $f$ to take only positive values (as otherwise the $ln$ of it makes no sense). Of course that can be amended easily.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f$ is differentiable and positive, then the derivative of $ln \circ f$ is $\frac{f'}{f}$.

Answer (score 1):

This can be split into two types of solutions;

Case 1:

Non Trivial solution. In this case, assume that $f(x)\neq 0$ then proceed by separating variables and integrating as done by @Peter Foreman

Case 2:

The obvious solution is $f(x)=0$ this is trivial.

From the two observation, the functions are given by $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=f_{0} e^{177x}$ where $f_{0}$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Except for $f(x)\equiv 0$, write $${f'(x)\over f(x)}=177$$ therefore $$\int {f'(x)\over f(x)}dx=\int {1\over f(x)}df(x)=\int 177d x$$which leads to $$\ln f(x)+C_1=177x+C_2$$therefore $$f(x)=C_3 \exp(177x)$$the only solutions ever!

Answer (score 0):

Recall the uniqueness theorem for first-order differential equations, which says that for a differential equation $y’=F(x,y)$, if both $F$ and $F_y$ are continuous functions in a rectangle around a point $(x_0,y_0)$, then there is a unique solution to $y’=F(x,y)$ passing through the point $(x_0,y_0)$. Now note that $F$ and $F_y$ are continuous in your case. What can you conclude about the solution that you obtained?